# how to access element by ID in DOM that has been appended with Jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

I am trying to have an img toggle that is appended to the DOM. The URL was appended through an array in a loop.

```
$('.bonesBtn').on('click', function() {
    $(this).data('clicked', true);

   var bonesBtnPress = $(this).attr('id');

   if ($('#'+ bonesBtnPress).data('clicked')){
         console.log('finding');
         $('#imgHumerus').toggle();
            }
```

Comment: Took a break and came back and figured it out by refactoring the code a bit. There was some selector confusion. $('.bonesBtn').on('click', function() {
 console.log('check check');
//console.log('#'+ bonesBtnPress);
var bonesBtnPress = $(this).attr('id');
var nBonesBtnPRess =  bonesBtnPress.substr(3);
 console.log(bonesBtnPress);
 console.log(nBonesBtnPRess);
 console.log('img'+ nBonesBtnPRess);
       $('#img'+nBonesBtnPRess).toggle();

});

});